How to deal with VAR model when covariance matrix is not positive define?
I am encountering the a couple of complications when trying to apply VAR model over a multivariate time series.
Dataset: the dataset is composed by time series data from several users. For each user, I have a number of features (e.g., F1, F2,...F32), among which one is the target one for forecasting, e.g. F29.
training_set: it is build by sliding time windows of 90 days, producing different blocks for each users, for example, for user i-th Xi=[<day1,...day89>, <day2,...day90>,...] Yi=[, , ,...]
Python Code (after normalized and made each feature stationary with up to second derivative):
 try: 
       model: VAR(training_set) 
       x = model.select_order(maxlags=90) 
       print(x.summary()) 
 except Exception as error: 
       print(error)

Issue 1: for most of the users, I got: "17 or 31t-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite."
Issue 2: For those users that I am able to run the above code with no errors, when analysing the Results for F29 (the target variable), it turns out that, the p-value <= 0.05 is in relation to different lags for different user, in correspondence to the same feature. For example, for the feature F20, the lag is 10 for user_3 and the lag is 12 for user_4.
In relation to Issue 1, I have searched and it seems that "the error happen when the covariance matrix does not appear numerically to be positive definite.". From this, I understand that there is an opposite signals characterizations in corresponding to the covariance computation. Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?
In relation to Issue 2: I could not find any useful way to address it. Any idea or help?

You are probably running out of data points. A single equation of a VAR(p) model for $k$ time series contains $pk$ slope coefficients. The entire model contains $pk^2$ slope coefficients. Their covariance matrix contains $\frac{(pk^2)(pk^2+1)}{2}$ elements. You need a lot of data points (time points) to be able to estimate these using least squares or maximum likelihood. (Add an intercept to bring these numbers even higher up.)

Thank you Richard. Yes, indeed, I probably do as I have only 500/600 data points for each of the 32 features. I am in the process of reducing the set of features now. What about the issue 2?

@CarloAllocca, I do not understand you question there. Could you elaborate? What do you mean by For example, for the feature F20, the lag is 10 for user_3 and the lag is 12 for user_4. and how is that related to p-values that you are referring to right before? It is entirely normal that some coefficients are insignificant while other are significant.

please allow me to be more specific.

please allow me to be more specific. Let's imagine I have User1_df(F1,...F20), User2_df(F1,...F20), ...User50_df(F1,...F20)  and F20 is my target, and the goal is to apply to apply VAR for forecasting F20. At the moment, I am applying VAR to a single Useri_df(F1,...F20). In this respect, Let's consider F13 as an example to forecast F20. I do a PACF, I find out  that the lag of F13 is 10 for user_3 and 12 for user_4? This pose the issue how to build the final model to predict over unseen users. Does this clarify to issue @Richard?

@CarloAllocca, this is clearer. Does that mean you have 50 VAR models (one per user) but would instead like to have a single VAR model that describes all users?

Yes, I would like to. Is stacking one user on the top of the other enough?

@CarloAllocca, stacking may be problematic, as the model will think that the last observation of user $i-1$ is the first lag of the first observation of user $i$. You will probably need another approach. Essentially, you want to fit 50 VAR models with a restriction that the coefficients are the same across thems. How to implement that algebraically or numerically is a question on its own. You could post it separately and edit this post to keep only your question 1. That would yield two well-focused posts instead of one that has multiple focuses (foci).

OK, sure, I will do that. Thank you
